# GridLayout. Check the amount of cells used

Tags: java, grid-layout

After creating the grill with "GridLayout":

```
supper(new GridLayout(rows, column));
```

I will add to demand content in each cell:

```
public void addButton(String name) {
 buttons = new JButton(name);
 add(buttons);
}
```

As I can I know the current number of cells used to keep a counter of addition and deletion?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check with [`Container.getComponentCount()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#getComponentCount%28%29).

Comment: are returning always the result of "rows x column", not those who are used.